# how to implement simple row count

Tags: r

I´m sorry to bother you with that simple question. however after spending a significant amount of time reading previous posts I could`t find a code for simple row count

my data has a variable which is measured in hours:

```
                             hours:       would like to get such count:
                                1           1
                                2           2
                               ...         ...
                               24          24
                                1          25
                                2          26
                                ...        ..
                               24          48
                               ..          ..
```

I tried without success:

```
           library(plyr)

           data$hours_count<-ddply(data, .(hours), nrow)

           data$hours_count<-sapply(data, FUN = function(x) count(x=hours, pattern = "\\n") + 1)


           data$hours_count<-sapply(data$hours,function(x) sum(hours))
```

Comment: Seems like `seq_along(data$hours)` or `1:nrow(data)`

Comment: Yes, thats it. Thank you so much.

Comment: Or just a `seq_len(nrow(data))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding answers from comments here to show that the question has been answered

You can do any of

- `seq_along(data$hours)`
- `1:nrow(data)`
- `seq_len(nrow(data))`